# Actix - How can I build a Web server to serve whole html files from gatsby deploy? not just 1 html file

Tags: rust, gatsby, actix-web, go-fiber

First of all I have tried to click on index.html that served from Actix, it is very fast ever.
...
I implement Web Server by GoFiber to serve static files, I use the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Static("/", "./public")

    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":8000"))
}
```

It works properly.

Then I try to implement a Web Server by Rust in Actix, I use the following code:

```
use actix_files as fs;
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            fs::Files::new("/", "./public")
                .show_files_listing()
                .use_last_modified(true),
        )
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:8000")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

It shows as the following image:
[image]

How can I change Actix code to serve the whole html files from gatsby deploy automatically like GoFiber?
When I click index.html, it works very well and I feel that it blazingly fast more than any other Web Server Platform that I have used.

Maybe I’m wrong in asking questions.
I can find the solution:

```
use actix_files as fs;
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            fs::Files::new("/", "./public")
                .show_files_listing()
                .index_file("index.html")
                .use_last_modified(true),
        )
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:8000")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: Per the linked question: `app.route("/", web::get().to(index))` where `index` (`async fn index(_req: HttpRequest) -> Result<NamedFile>`) is an async function which serves the file of your choosing.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger this is what I’m looking for use actix_files as fs;
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            fs::Files::new("/", "./public")
                .show_files_listing()
                .index_file("index.html")
                .use_last_modified(true),
        )
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:8000")?
    .run()
    .await
}